# Remove duplicated codes from a generator in Python

Tags: python

```
def generator():
    for i in range(10):
        yield "foo" + "baz"

    for i in range(10):
        yield "bar" + "baz"
```

I want to make the code like this:

```
def baz(s):
    for i in range(10):
        yield s + "baz"

def generator():
    baz("foo")
    baz("bar")
```

However, this code behaves differently.

How can I get rid of duplicated code including `yield` in a generator?

P.S. I found `yield from`. It's exactly which I want, but my project is in Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rewrite it like this:

```
def baz(s):
    for i in range(10):
        yield s + "baz"

def generator():
    for s in ["foo", "baz"]:
        for b in baz(s):
            yield b
```

Answer (score 1):

You could recode to use `itertools` as follows:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

def generator():
    for i in chain(repeat('foobaz', 10), repeat('barbaz', 10)):
        yield i

for x in generator():
    print x
```

Giving you:

```
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
foobaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
barbaz
```

Or as a simple list:

```
from itertools import repeat, chain

def generator():
    return list(chain(repeat('foobaz', 10), repeat('barbaz', 10)))

print generator()
```

Giving:

```
['foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'foobaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz', 'barbaz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Martin's answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/35286012/901925 could be cast as:

```
def baz(s):
    for i in range(4):yield s+'baz'

def g2():
    return itertools.chain(baz('foo'),baz('bar'))

In [411]: list(g2())
Out[411]: 
['foobaz',
 'foobaz',
 'foobaz',
 'foobaz',
 'barbaz',
 'barbaz',
 'barbaz',
 'barbaz']
```